# setText("") android error group=0x4001b188

Tags: android

i got problem when make edit text empty when a button clicked. The DDMS said it was error with uncaught exception group=0x4001b188.
here is y code

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    float fm_value_pdty;
    Button calc_fm_pdty, dt_pdty_calc, loader_pdty_calc;
    TextView fm_value_pdty_txt;
    EditText DT_count, Loader_count;
    public EditText DT_Pdty;
    public EditText Loader_Pdty;
    public static float vdtpdty;
    public static float vloaderpdty;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fm_value_pdty=(float) 0;
        calc_fm_pdty = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcpdty);
        dt_pdty_calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcpdty_dt);
        loader_pdty_calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcpdty_loader);
        fm_value_pdty_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fm_pdty_value);
        DT_Pdty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DTPdty_ET);
        Loader_Pdty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Loader_CT_ET);
        vdtpdty=(float) 0.0;
        vloaderpdty=(float) 0.0;


        calc_fm_pdty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //if (DT_CT.getText().toString() <>""){
                    if ((DT_Pdty.getText().toString()!=null) &&  (Loader_Pdty.getText().toString()!=null))  {
                        fm_value_pdty = ((float) Integer.parseInt(DT_Pdty.getText().toString()))/((float) Integer.parseInt(Loader_Pdty.getText().toString()));
                        fm_value_pdty_txt.setText("Fleet Matching value is " + fm_value_pdty);
                    }
                    else if ((DT_Pdty.getText().toString()==null) ||  (Loader_Pdty.getText().toString()==null)) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                        dlgAlert.setMessage("Please input the DT Productivty and Loader Productivty");
                        dlgAlert.setTitle("Data is empty");
                        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
                        dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                        dlgAlert.create().show();
                    }
            }
        });
        dt_pdty_calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dt_pdty.vloaderpdty=vloaderpdty;
                DT_Pdty.setText("");
                Loader_Pdty.setText("");
                Intent pdty = new Intent(Main.this, dt_pdty.class);
                startActivity(pdty);
                DT_Pdty.setText(Float.toString(vdtpdty));
                Loader_Pdty.setText(Float.toString(vloaderpdty));
            }
        });
        loader_pdty_calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v2) {
                ld_pdty.vdtpdty=vdtpdty;
                DT_Pdty.setText("");
                Loader_Pdty.setText("");
                Intent pdty = new Intent(Main.this, ld_pdty.class);
                startActivity(pdty);
                DT_Pdty.setText(Float.toString(vdtpdty));
                Loader_Pdty.setText(Float.toString(vloaderpdty));
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

the code is simple when i try to activate an activity with a button first the edit text is emptied and that activity start and after the activity finish the edit text that has emptied is fill with calculated value from the activity.
i want to make a program that has two edit text and two button. the first edit text will be filled with result from first button and same as the other edit text and button. the problem that i get result for first button but when i run second activity from second button i get an error. from the logcat it is because the view of first edit text. i already updated my post with logcat.

```
08-20 19:52:47.924: D/AndroidRuntime(237): Shutting down VM
08-20 19:52:47.958: W/dalvikvm(237): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
08-20 19:52:47.958: E/AndroidRuntime(237): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.example.fleetmatcher.Main$2.onClick(Main.java:66)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 19:52:48.201: I/dalvikvm(237): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
08-20 19:52:48.422: I/dalvikvm(237): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-20 19:52:50.620: I/Process(237): Sending signal. PID: 237 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the logcat outputs plz?

Comment: try to set like settext(null)

Comment: what is the dt_pdty.vloaderpdty ?

Comment: Do you wish to set a hint in the edit Text? Hint can be set in the xml file, so on clicking the edit Text content automatically gets cleared.

Comment: i have editted my post with my log cat. i have try settext(null) and did'nt work. dt_pdty.vloaderpdty is a float variable from dt_pdty class. I did'nt try to make a edit text hint, but I try to make the edit text is filled with result from other activity. there's a problem if i back to the previous activity with edit text filled.

Answer (score 0):

Will need your logcat to know exact problem. But a few observations:

1. Dont try to update the EditText after you do startActivity(pdty).
2. You dont need to clear the EditText to replace the text, i.e you dont need to do `edittext.settext("");`
3. If you do want to clear Edittext, there is another way: `edittext.gettext.clear();`

Hope this is useful.

Comment: i want to make a program that has two edit text and two button. the first edit text will be filled with result from first button and same as the other edit text and button. the problem that i get result for first button but when i run second activity from second button i get an error. from the logcat it is because the view of first edit text. i already updated my post with logcat.

Comment: im sorry. i has post the entire but i dont know why it didnt in my post. thanks for your help.

Comment: i has added my log cat. please help me with my problem.